# Microsoft Access search form with multiple date ranges (each range relating to a different field)

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, database-design

I've been banging my head against a wall for hours trying to put together a (fairly simple) database (and corresponding forms) for the office.

We have two main tables - `CLIENT DETAILS` and `SALES` (1-to-Many relationship via `CLIENT NUMBER`).
I've created a form that enables the user to search for ANY matching data from within the form
e.g.

```
Field: BUSINESS NAME
Table: CLIENT DETAILS
Criteria: Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![BUSINESS_NAME] & "*" Or Is Null
```

This works fine for the majority of the form, however I've been running into major dramas when trying to incorporate date ranges.
e.g.

```
Field: CONTACT DATE
Table: SALES
Criteria: >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CONTACT_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]!

[CONTACT_DATE_2] Or Is Null

Field: PAID DATE<br>
Table: SALES<br>
Criteria: >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_2] Or Is Null

Field: CANCELLED DATE<br>
Table: SALES<br>
Criteria: >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_2] Or Is Null
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is a query that returns records that match the search terms i.e. Business Name = Mybiz (or Myb*) AND Phone = 555 55555 etc AND on either CONTACT_DATE, PAID_DATE or CANCELLED DATE.
The user will only ever enter one set of dates at any given time.

*(If necessary, the individual date ranges can also be enabled/disabled via checkbox depending on what is required - this is something I've set up but is probably pointless)*

Edit: Here's the SQL as it stands now ->

```
SELECT [CLIENT DETAILS].*, SALES.*
FROM [CLIENT DETAILS] INNER JOIN SALES ON [CLIENT DETAILS].[CLIENT NUMBER] = SALES.[CLIENT NUMBER]
WHERE ((([CLIENT DETAILS].[BUSINESS NAME]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![BUSINESS_NAME] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[BUSINESS NAME]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].ADDRESS) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![ADDRESS] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].ADDRESS) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].CITY) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![CITY] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].CITY) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].STATE) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![STATE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].STATE) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].POSTCODE) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![POSTCODE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].POSTCODE) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].PHONE) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![PHONE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].PHONE) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[FAX NUMBER]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![FAX] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[FAX NUMBER]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].EMAIL) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![EMAIL] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].EMAIL) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].WEBSITE) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![WEBSITE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].WEBSITE) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].COMMENTS) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![COMMENTS] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].COMMENTS) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[PHONE 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![PHONE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[PHONE 2]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[ADDRESS 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![Address] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[ADDRESS 2]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[CITY 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![City] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[CITY 2]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[STATE 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![State] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[STATE 2]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[POSTCODE 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![POSTCODE] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[POSTCODE 2]) Is Null)
AND (([CLIENT DETAILS].[EMAIL 2]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![EMAIL] & "*" Or ([CLIENT DETAILS].[EMAIL 2]) Is Null)
AND ((SALES.[SALE NUMBER]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![SALE_NUMBER] & "*" Or (SALES.[SALE NUMBER]) Is Null)
AND ((SALES.BOOK) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![BOOK] & "*" Or (SALES.BOOK) Is Null)
AND ((SALES.SALESPERSON) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![SALESPERSON] & "*" Or (SALES.SALESPERSON) Is Null)
AND ((SALES.[CONTACT PERSON]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![CONTACT] & "*" Or (SALES.[CONTACT PERSON]) Is Null)
AND ((SALES.[PAID DATE])>=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_1] And (SALES.[PAID DATE])<=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_2])
AND ((SALES.[CANCELLED DATE])>=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_1] And (SALES.[CANCELLED DATE])<=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_2]));
```

The last two entries should be the ones that are dependent on the IF statements.

Comment: What problem(s) do you have ? Question isn't so clear.  
Anyway I already suspect that you forgot to handle the `Nulls`

Comment: Thanks iDevlop for your quick response.

Comment: Ok so when I run the query with date ranges blank, it only returns records that have null entries. Makes sense.

When I key in PAID_DATE_1 and PAID_DATE_2, it returns entries within those dates AND null entries. Also makes sense, but obviously not what I want.

When I key in CANCELLED_DATE_1 and CANCELLED_DATE_2, it throws up an error: 'This expression is typed incorrectly...' <- Actually cancel that, this only occurs if I've enabled & then disabled PAID_DATE_1 and PAID_DATE_2 on the form. With a fresh form, it does the same as PAID_DATE_1 and PAID_DATE_2.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a radio button next to each date field.  Make all date fields disabled on form load.  When you click a radio button, it will enable the corresponding date field and disable all others (so that if they click on another radio button you don't have multiple date fields enabled simultaneously).  Then, in VBA behind the form, only use one of those criteria statements to build the search SQL based on which radio button is enabled.  It will require one extra mouse click from your users, but I can't see how you're gonna do that filter any other way.

You would do something like this, which is completely untested "aircode" but should give you a start:

```
sSQL = "SELECT ClientDetails.*, Sales.* FROM ClientDetails "
sSQL = sSQL & "LEFT JOIN SALES on ClientDetails.ClientNumber = Sales.ClientNumber " 
sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE BusinessName Like "*" & [Forms]![FINDClient]![BUSINESS_NAME] & "*" Or Is Null "
If Radio1.Enabled = True then
  sSQL = sSQL & "AND ContactDate >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CONTACT_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CONTACT_DATE_2] Or Is Null;"
ElseIf Radio2.Enabled = True then
  sSQL = sSQL & "AND PaidDate >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_2] Or Is Null;"
Elseif Radio3.Enabled = True then
  sSQL = sSQL & "AND CancelledDate >=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_1] And <=[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_2] Or Is Null ;"
Else
Endif

Forms![FINDClient].RecordSource = sSQL
```

Comment: Hi Bones, thanks a lot for your reply...
I feel like I'm so close to wrapping my head around it, yet it continues to evade me. Sorry, I'm an Access n00b. If it's possible, I would really appreciate you tinkering a bit with the SQL I currently have in place...I've trimmed the IF statements out (because they weren't working on my end anyway).

Now if I could just figure out how to get the code in here without overshooting the character limit...

Comment: You can save a few characters by changing this part: AND ((SALES.[PAID DATE]) BETWEEN [Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_1] And [Forms]![FINDClient]![PAID_DATE_2])
AND ((SALES.[CANCELLED DATE]) BETWEEN[Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_1] And [Forms]![FINDClient]![CANCELLED_DATE_2]));  But I don't think you always want to check both PAID DATE and CANCELLED DATE, do you?  That's why I'm saying you need to build the SQL string dynamically in VBA code, you CAN'T create a static query and capture that properly.